# Does $[E:F]=|Aut(E/F)|$ imply Galois extension?

Tags: proof-verification, field-theory

Let $E/F$ be a **finite** field extension such that $[E:F]=|Aut(E/F)|$.

Then, is $E/F$ Galois?

Even though I have proven it, I'm not sure of it. Is this really true?

Here's how I proved it:

Let $\bar F$ be an algebraic closure of $F$ such that $F\leq E\leq \bar F$.

Let $A$ be the set of all field monomorphisms from $E$ to $\bar F$ over $F$.

Then, $Aut(E/F)\subset A$ and $|A|=[E:F]_s$. Hence $|Aut(E/F)|\leq [E:F]_s$.

Since $E/F$ is finite, $[E:F]_s \leq [E:F] = |Aut(E/F)|$, which leads $[E:F]=[E:F]_s=|Aut(E/F)|$.

Hence, $E/F$ is separable and $A=Aut(E/F)$.

Let $\sigma\in Aut(\bar F/F)$.

Then, the restriction $\sigma_E$ is in $A$, hence in $Aut(E/F)$. Thus, $\sigma(E)=E$ for each $\sigma\in Aut(\bar F/F)$.

Thus, $E/F$ is normal, hence Galois. Q.E.D.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: You take $\sigma \in \mathrm{Aut}(\bar{F}/F)$ and then assume it restricts to an automorphism of $E$. Why is this justified?

Comment: @MarkWildon Since I have shown above that $A=Aut(E/F)$.

Comment: I see. It now looks fine to me.